# Fade text to white without hindering hover and selection

Tags: css

I want to fade an article's content to white to signify that further content can be unlocked. I can achieve this by adding an :after element with a white gradient.

But this techniques makes the text under the area under the gradient awkwardly unselectable and unresponsive to hover effects.

How can I produce a similar effect, and still let the user interact properly with the content underneath the gradient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `pointer-events: none` on `:after`
More info and an example: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/

Here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/zakkain/pen/dseHt used in aforementioned example.

I have also added a fiddle as an example: **https://jsfiddle.net/quzoqone/4/**

Answer (score 0):

Use this library: [AnimateCSS](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

There's a lot of cool effects including fadeIn